# What is the fastest way to connect to a database from the web front end?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

For example, in the following code (using node-postgres), we connect to the client, query and then end.

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'dbuser',
  host: 'database.server.com',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'secretpassword',
  port: 3211,
})

pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  pool.end()
})

const client = new Client({
  user: 'dbuser',
  host: 'database.server.com',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'secretpassword',
  port: 3211,
})
client.connect()

client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res)
  client.end()
})
```

Does that mean we should create a connection each time we intend to query the database ? Is there a faster way ?

Would you suggest using something besides node-postgres?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest sequelize ORM so you will don't  need to worry about other database operation. It also supports PostgreSQL and will maintain and end connection for you its mean just need to create connection and Sequelize will do remaining for you boom it's amazing.

> Sequelize is a promise-based ORM for Node.js v4 and up. It supports the dialects PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and MSSQL and features solid transaction support, relations, read replication and more.

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});

// Or you can simply use a connection uri
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname');
```

You can use the `.authenticate()` function like this to test the connection.

```
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

For more detail http://docs.sequelizejs.com/